# Dog cat classification using Perceptron in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, perceptron

Hi guys I want to classify dogs and cats using Perceptron but i've got some errors 
First I take 20 images from training set,10 cats then 10 dogs, cats are labeled zero `y_train.append(0)` and dogs are labeled one `y_train.append(1)`

```
x_train,y_train = [],[]
for i in range(10):
    img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Hi-XV\\Desktop\\dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition\\train\\cat.' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    img = cv2.resize(img,(64,64))
    x_train.append(img)
    y_train.append(0)
    img2 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Hi-XV\\Desktop\\dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition\\train\\dog.' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    img2 = cv2.resize(img,(64,64))
    x_train.append(img2)
    y_train.append(1)
```

This is how I process it:

```
x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)

x_train_flatten = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1).T
x_train = x_train_flatten / 255
```

This is my sigmoid function always return a value between 0 and 1:

```
def sigmoid(self,z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

This is my backpropagation function:

```
def propaganate(self,X,Y,w,b):
    A = self.sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X) +b)
    m = X.shape[1]
    dw = np.dot(X, (A - Y).T) / m
    db = np.sum(A-Y)/m
    cost = (-1  / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - A))
    return dw,db,cost
```

This is my main function with gradient descent:

```
def optimize(self,learningRate=0.005,steps=2000):
    X = self.x_train
    Y = self.y_train
    w = self.w
    b = self.b
    costs =[]
    for i in range(steps):
        dw,db,cost =self.propaganate(X,Y,w,b)

        w = w - learningRate*dw
        b = b - learningRate*db
        if i%100 ==0:
            costs.append(cost)
            print('cost after %i: %f' %(i,cost))
    return w,b
```

This is my predict function:

```
def predict(self,image):
    w,b = self.optimize()
    m = image.shape[1]
    w = w.reshape((image.shape[0],-1))
    Y_prediction = np.zeros((1,m))
    A = self.sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,image)+b)
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        Y_prediction[0,i] =A[0,i]
    print(Y_prediction)
    return Y_prediction
```

Finally I call `pct.predict(predict_imgs)` and this is how it logs:

> cost after 0: 13.862944
>   cost after 100: 0.017974
>   cost after 200: 0.011118
>   cost after 300: 0.008078
>   cost after 400: 0.006354
>   cost after 500: 0.005242
>   cost after 600: 0.004465
>   cost after 700: 0.003890
>   cost after 800: 0.003447
>   cost after 900: 0.003096
>   cost after 1000: 0.002810
>   cost after 1100: 0.002573
>   cost after 1200: 0.002373
>   cost after 1300: 0.002202
>   cost after 1400: 0.002054
>   cost after 1500: 0.001926
>   cost after 1600: 0.001812
>   cost after 1700: 0.001711
>   cost after 1800: 0.001621
>   cost after 1900: 0.001540

So the cost appears to be correct since It's almost 0
But then I predict one dog image and this is how i do it:

```
predict_imgs = []
pd_img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Hi-XV\\Desktop\\dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels- 
edition\\train\\dog.1.jpg')
pd_img = cv2.resize(pd_img,(64,64))
predict_imgs.append(pd_img)
predict_imgs = np.array(predict_imgs)

predict_imgs_flatten = predict_imgs.reshape(pd_img.shape[0],-1).T
predict_imgs = predict_imgs_flatten/255
pct.predict(predict_imgs)
```

This is how it logged:

> [[0.47129622 0.47146358 0.47072547 0.46926181 0.46849233 0.4705466
>     0.4713464  0.47103178 0.47406489 0.47669844 0.47609287 0.47602436
>     0.47432492 0.46869344 0.4653232  0.46576656 0.46390416 0.46274703
>     0.46455358 0.46425507 0.46637787 0.46493939 0.46585933 0.46551723
>     0.46313767 0.46074716 0.45894883 0.45560602 0.45442201 0.45338179
>     0.45419183 0.45414762 0.45349525 0.45224447 0.45072343 0.45040515
>     0.44871289 0.44694917 0.44369839 0.44729202 0.44997111 0.44890832
>     0.44254292 0.43972149 0.4354109  0.43391902 0.43312538 0.43134105
>     0.42976022 0.42922733 0.42829998 0.42911856 0.42773902 0.42823065
>     0.4274165  0.42786264 0.42790718 0.42816487 0.42216149 0.41795934
>     0.41516696 0.41230804 0.41243036 0.41221888]]

I tried with a cat image:

> [[0.46602192 0.46570703 0.46540704 0.4669786  0.46794146 0.46773242
>     0.4684889  0.4683816  0.46921272 0.46943627 0.46954064 0.47158274
>     0.4749414  0.47375206 0.47201231 0.47086452 0.47094515 0.47293698
>     0.47381821 0.47411287 0.47467158 0.47491538 0.47760668 0.47640458
>     0.47514657 0.47359331 0.47391838 0.47318598 0.47173989 0.47296217
>     0.47173741 0.47185791 0.47241618 0.47475851 0.47406301 0.4755808
>     0.47666993 0.47613153 0.47499163 0.475437   0.47435883 0.47370117
>     0.47281707 0.47372429 0.47287648 0.47400302 0.47556063 0.47517845
>     0.47593115 0.47595672 0.47693075 0.47990405 0.47702912 0.47646767
>     0.47643149 0.47786475 0.47577853 0.47806219 0.4775023  0.47835029
>     0.47919827 0.48055778 0.48172249 0.48003663]]

Still almost the same with that dog image above. Something's wrong here.
I need help.
This is my full code:

> https://github.com/lanlehoang67/PerceptronDogCatClassification/blob/master/perceptron.py

This is the dataset:

> https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/data

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Perceptron models are not performant on image classification. Your data is not linearly separable and high-dimensional, from a theoretical point of view a simple Perceptron algorithm has no reason to perform well. Usually, convolutional neural networks are used to classify images, or at least multi-layer perceptron (even though it is not very performant either).

If you were aware of that and are asking about an issue about your code itself, I can go deeper in your code though.

Comment: yes I was aware of that because I used keras CNN to classify dogs and cats successfully